# Color picker of Div gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with a gradient on i and want to pick the color of a pixel of it.
I really can't figure out how to do it.

This is the CSS of the div

```
#blackToTransparent
{    
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
```

With a canvas it seems to be easier but the problem is that i don't have a canvas in my project.
Since i don't really have an approach i would be very thankfull for every hint or tipp

Comment: Sorry that i don't have an approach so far i am really hoping for a hint that helps me on my way, that pushes me into the water. I am not trying to get a complete answer here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome as a browser, download an extension called: "ColorZilla"

It will allow you to click on the color on your screen and get the color instantly.

And if you are using a different browser,, just google for color picker extension (for the browser you're using).

It's one of the so many ways to do it.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Developer Tools of any browser (click F12)
and somethere is a small color Pipette (Ithink In IE in the Top Left Corner / FF top right, but you might Need to activate it)